# Subset data based on input and create a plots with this data on Rshiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, subset

Roman history fan here, so I have a dataframe with the name of two legions (`fifth` and `tirteenth`), their casualties (numerical value), and the moral of the troops (`high`, `medium`, `low`).

I want to know (boxplot) the relationship between moral (x axis) and casualties (y axis), and also subset by legion:

```
Legion <- c("Fifth", "Fifth", "Fifth","Fifth","Fifth","Tirteenth","Tirteenth", "Tirteenth", "Tirteenth","Tirteenth")
Casualties <- c(13, 34,23,123,0,234,3,67,87,4)
Moral <- c("High", "Medium", "Low","High", "Medium", "Low","High", "Medium", "Low", "High")
romans <- data.frame(Legion, Casualties, Moral)
```

Please notice that this is a toy example. In the real data (no romans) we have several variables for each of the axis, so we ask the user to load the data, and then select which variables he wants to use for each axis.

This is what I have:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

not_sel <- "Not Selected"

main_page <- tabPanel(
  title = "Romans",
  titlePanel("Romans"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      title = "Inputs",
      fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
      selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
      selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
      selectInput("factor", "Select factor", choices = c(not_sel)),
      br(),
      actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          title = "Plot",
          plotOutput("plot_1")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

draw_plot_1 <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2, factor){

  
  if(num_var_1 != not_sel & num_var_2 != not_sel & factor == not_sel){
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes_string(x = num_var_1, y = num_var_2, fill= num_var_2)) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      theme_bw()
  }
  
  else if(num_var_1 != not_sel & num_var_2 != not_sel & factor != not_sel){
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes_string(x = num_var_1, y = num_var_2, fill = factor)) +
      geom_boxplot() + 
      theme_bw()
  }
}


ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Plotter",
  theme = shinytheme("yeti"),
  main_page
)

server <- function(input, output){
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10*1024^2)
  
  data_input <- reactive({
    req(input$xlsx_input)
    inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "factor", choices = choices)
  })
  
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  factor <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$factor)
  
    plot_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    draw_plot_1(data_input(), num_var_1(), num_var_2(), factor())
  })
  
  
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlot(plot_1())
   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've been trying different methods to:

- First, let the user select which legion wants to plot.
- Implement this selection in plot.

So far, the plot looks like this:

[image: Boxplot]
Any help given would be really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
Legion <- c("Fifth", "Fifth", "Fifth","Fifth","Fifth","Tirteenth","Tirteenth", "Tirteenth", "Tirteenth","Tirteenth")
Casualties <- c(13, 34,23,123,0,234,3,67,87,4)
Moral <- c("High", "Medium", "Low","High", "Medium", "Low","High", "Medium", "Low", "High")
romans <- data.frame(Legion, Casualties, Moral)

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

not_sel <- "Not Selected"

main_page <- tabPanel(
  title = "Romans",
  titlePanel("Romans"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      title = "Inputs",
      fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
      selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
      selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
      selectInput("factor", "Select factor", choices = c(not_sel)), uiOutput("leg"),
      br(),
      actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          title = "Plot",
          plotOutput("plot_1")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

draw_plot_1 <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2, factor){
  print(num_var_1)

  if(num_var_1 != not_sel & num_var_2 != not_sel & factor == not_sel){
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = .data[[num_var_1]], y = .data[[num_var_2]], fill= .data[[num_var_2]])) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      theme_bw()
  }

  else if(num_var_1 != not_sel & num_var_2 != not_sel & factor != not_sel){
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = .data[[num_var_1]], y = .data[[num_var_2]], fill = .data[[factor]])) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      theme_bw()
  }
}


ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Plotter",
  theme = shinytheme("yeti"),
  main_page
)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10*1024^2)

server <- function(input, output){


  data_input <- reactive({
    # req(input$xlsx_input)
    # inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    # read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    romans
  })


  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "factor", choices = choices)
  })

  output$leg <- renderUI({
    req(input$factor,data_input())
    if (input$factor != not_sel) {
      b <- unique(data_input()[[input$factor]])
      pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_factors',
                  label = 'Select factors',
                  choices = c(b[1:length(b)]), selected=b[1],
                  multiple = TRUE,  ###  if you wish to select multiple factor values; then deselect NONE
                  options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))

    }
  })

  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  factor <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$factor)

  plot_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    #print(input$selected_factors)
    req(input$factor,data_input())
    if (!is.null(input$selected_factors)) df <- data_input()[data_input()[[input$factor]] %in% input$selected_factors,]
    else df <- data_input()
    draw_plot_1(df, num_var_1(), num_var_2(), factor())
  })

  output$plot_1 <- renderPlot(plot_1())

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please note that you can use `multiple = TRUE` option in `pickerInput()`, if you wish to select multiple factors.

Comment: Thank you @YBS. That was really helpful. There is one minor inconvenience, and that is that factor remains unselected (choosing only X and Y variables) no plot is printed. But I couldn't figure out why, as the plot function wasn't touched

Comment: That if because there is a req() with factors.  So, no plot if you don't select factors.  If you want the plot with all possible factors, it can be set-up that way.

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: That was perfect @YBS. Thank you!